# Degradable link - SEO for Ajax Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, seo

There seems to be a lot of solutions to degradable javascript links so I am wondering which is seen to be the best approach. 
An improtant consideration is that search engines now seem to be indexing AJAX content and I want to make this as easy as possible.

http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/2hFWj/3/

```
$(function () {
    $('#next').click(function (e) {
        alert("Test!")
    });
```

Is this the best way of adding a progressive enhancement link on my site?
Can google follow the javascript route on this link?

Comment: That's one way, see this article for another one: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/

Comment: Thats the thing though, I can't see on there how I should be formatting my degradable ajax links

Comment: From SEO point of view (link juice) Google will not count this link. You can add & hide 2nd menu with z-index - hidden for visitors but crawlable for googlebot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using non-obtrusive javascript as in your example, you can be sure that google will follow and take in consideration your HTML link:

```
<a href="/next" id="next">Next</a>
```

To test it try:

- Use Google Web Master "Fetch as Google" https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/158587?hl=en
- Disable Javascript in the browser, if you see the html the link, it will be visible to Google
- Use a spyder emulator, so you can see simulate how a search engine see your page ex: http://www.webconfs.com/search-engine-spider-simulator.php